# Не уверен в логике данного stream

Tags: java, потоки-данных, map, java-8

У меня есть данный стрим, я хотел чтобы вы подтвердили, что я правильно принцип его работы.

```
return groupedTransfers.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> isEnabled(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Я понимаю, что стрим фильтруется по функции `isEnabled`

Далее идет `collect`, и тут уже я не уверен, берется каждое значение `key` и `value`, к ним применяется `merge` функция `(x, y) -> y`, это значит что дубликаты `key` будут убраны для каждого уникального `value`? Как в целом работает `merge` в данном случае?

В итоге все записывается в новый `LinkedHashMap`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(x, y) -> y
Данная функция отвечает за то какое значение будет присвоено ключу в случае если в стриме будут дубликаты.
Например добавилась пара
а:б
и следом есть пара
а:с
(x, y) -> y
 Данная функция указывает на то что в конечной мапе должно остаться значение принадлежащее второй паре то есть
а:с

Comment: Именно это я и хотел узнать, спасибо.